# Cross Referencing not referring bibliography in elsarticle

Tags: cross-referencing

I am working on a paper for Elsevier, but the cross reference is not referring to bibliography , as it appear disabled . My code is here

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{lineno}         
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[nodots,nocompress]{numcompress}
\usepackage{setspace}


\journal{Computer Networks}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}



\title{Wireless Sensor Networks Routing: Key Challenges and Open Issues}


\author[a]{Palvinder Singh Mann\corref{cor1}}
\ead{psmaan@hotmail.com}
\author[b]{Satvir Singh}
\ead{satvir15@gmail.com}
\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author.Tel.:+91-9888395367 fax:+91-0181-2205852}

\address[a]{Department of Information Technology, DAV Institute of Engineering and Technology, Jalandhar,Punjab,India.144008.}
\address[b]{Department of Electronics and Communication Engineering, Saheed Bhagat Singh State Technical Campus, Ferozepur, Punjab, India.152004.}

\begin{abstract}
Wireless sensor networks (WSNs) enable new applications and require non-conventional paradigms for protocol design. Owing to the requirements for self-organization, scalability and primarily low energy consumption needs, a proper balance between communication and data processing capabilities must be maintained. This motivates a huge effort in research activities and investments on this field for past few years. At present most of the research on WSNs has concentrated on the design of energy and computationally efficient algorithms and routing protocols with application domain restricted to simple data-oriented monitoring. In this paper, we presented a comprehensive analysis on WSNs routing with key challenges for development of protocol designs. At last we discussed some open issues for future directions in WSNs for research contributions.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Wireless sensor networks, self-organization, scalability, routing protocols


\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

%% main text

\section{Introduction}


Wireless Sensor Networks (WSNs) contain self-configured, distributed, autonomous and resource empowered sensor nodes that monitor physical or environmental activities, such as humidity, temperature, sound, vibration or pollutants in a specific area of operation\cite{akkaya2005survey}. Sensor nodes \cite{abbasi2007survey}cooperatively \cite{al2004routing}pass their sensed data through the wireless\cite{bi2010ant} network to a main location, known as sink or base station where the data can be monitored and analyzsed for decision making.


\subsection{Subsection One}



\subsection{Subsection Two}



\section{References}


\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{Ref}




\end{document}
```

Comment: We can't check your file because we don't have `Ref.bib` or `model1-num-names.bst` You should supply a short sample .bib file and perhaps a link to `model1-num-names.bst`. It is also unclear what the sentence "the cross reference is not referring to bibliography" means. Describe what happens and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Well problem with my output file is that the in text citations appears disabled and they do not point to bibliography references as it happens with other files.

Comment: I don't know what "appears disabled" means. Nor do I know what "they do not point to bibliography" means. I ask again: *describe what happens* -- tell what appears in your document at the citation, and what error messages occur (if any). Then *describe how it differs from what you want* -- tell what you expect to appear. Also, if possible, add a short .bib file to your question and provide a link for downloading the bibstyle file `model1-num-names.bst`.

Comment: Mr. Dan, thanks a lot for your support.  Well Sir my in text citations appears perfect as [1],with no error message at compilation,but the problem is that when I point my mouse on [1] , it does not take me to bibliography reference to which it refers means its look diabled. This is just my problem.

Comment: If you want to jump from the citation to the bibliography in your PDF file, you need `\usepackage{hyperref}`. It should usually be the last package loaded.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Dan I got the solution of my problem through \usepackage{hyperref} and its working !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump from the citation to the bibliography in your PDF file, you need `\usepackage{hyperref}`. It should usually be the last package loaded.

Comment: Anybody got a dupe at hand?